# Boot from USB not working

Tags: boot, live-usb, startup, reinstall

I created a bootable USB using Ubuntu 14.04 Startup Disk Creator. Restarted, F12, chose option 4 - USB and have a blank screen. It probably stays forever. I gave up after 30 minutes. I have created another USB disk using Windows and I will try with this one after work. I just need to know if there is something that needs cleaning up before I can proceed. Thanks.

Comment: For windows, try and use Rufus boot loader

Comment: Do you have a UEFI/Legacy/CSM system? Did you disable secure boot/fast boot? Make sure to format your USB as GPT for UEFI if you have a UEFI/CSM system.

Comment: @Owen Hines - I used Rufus to create a new usb that i havent tried yet.

Comment: @patrick yi - how do I check and change the UEFi and secure boot? When I go to BIOS, I do not have an option for changing these things. Do I need to use terminal? I have a Lenovo V570 that originally ran windows 7. I upgraded to Windows 10 and it crashed. I then installed Ubuntu using Wubi a year ago and haven't touched it since.

Comment: When you select "boot options" in the BIOS, does it say "Legacy", "UEFI", "CSM", or a combination of those?

Comment: I made a USB using Rufus tool and tried it on a windows pc at work. It booted up to USB fine giving options like normal. That same USB still does not work on this laptop.

Comment: @patrick yi - no. Under SECURITY, I only have two options: Set supervisor password and set hard disk password

Comment: @JustinSaenz Is that it? There is no boot, advanced, information tab?

Comment: It says at the top Phoenix SecureCore Taino Setup. The tabs are Information, Configuration, SECURITY, Boot, and Exit. Under Boot, it shows the Boot Priority Order. I get to this menu using F2 at boot. I can also get to this screen with f12 then tabbing over to Apps.